# bufexplorer.vim plugin doesn't load

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-bufexplorer

I installed ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso on VirtualBox 6.1.28.  It is my first foray into virtual machines and Linux.

I installed Vim 8.1 according to [this page](https://superuser.com/a/332929).  The `:scriptnames` command shows that the first of the following two files doesn't load, even though the second one does:

- /usr/share/vim/addons/plugin/bufexplorer.vim,
- /usr/share/vim/addons/plugin/ChristiansHi20150126.vim [1]

In unix file access vernacular, both files have "read" permission for "group" and "other".

**What would cause this?**

My Vim 8.2 on Cygwin loads both plugins just fine, and I've been using both for many years, through various versions of Vim.  For Vim 8.2 on Cygwin, the `plugin` folder is a subfolder of `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles`.

P.S. I want to use this old version of `bufexplorer` because I've hacked it to display `~/` instead of `/home/User.Name/`, which makes better use of limited screen space.

**Notes**

[1] Code adapted from a [usenet contributor](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_use/c/_vbtxlld318)

Comment: If found that creating a symbolic link from `vimfiles` to `addons` causes the plugins to be loaded.  So the reason why one of the two files above appeared to be loaded was probably because I manually sourced it, or some-such.  More web searching reveals that there is an entire layer of vim-addon management of which I was unaware.

Comment: The list of directories under which Vim will look for `plugin/*.vim` can be found in the [`'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) variable, which you can see with `:set rtp?`. The documentation indicates it typically includes `$VIM/vimfiles` by default, but not `$VIM/addons`. I wonder if an older version of Vim used to use `addons`? Or maybe a specific Linux/Unix distribution of Vim used to customize to include that directory? In any way, you *could* update your vimrc to include `$VIM/addons` in that list, or move your files to the locations Vim recognizes...

Comment: @filbranden: You're right, `rtp` points to `/etc/vim/vimfiles`.  The `addons` folder might be left over from the `vim tiny` that came with Ubuntu. I can't even invoke it anymore to check its `rtp`. The Bash command `where -a vim` shows two locations, both pointing to `/etc/alternatives/vim`, which points to `/etc/bin/vim.gtk3`. The only other Vim-like files in `/etc/alternatives` is `vimdiff`, which also points to `/etc/bin/vim.gtk3`.  Is your comment worth posting as an answer, or should this question be removed?

Comment: Yes, I'll post that as an answer. I find it a bit odd that vim tiny would consider `addons` as a valid runtime directory, but on the other hand it's definitely plausible... Let me dig a little deeper to see if I can find something that may have configured that name somewhere to make a somewhat better hypothesis. Thanks!

Comment: There are other possible explanations for the `addons` folder.  It might have to do with the [vim-addon-manager](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905) and/or might have come with the Ubuntu ISO image.  It might have been installed when I [installed Vim](https://superuser.com/questions/187537/copy-to-system-clipboard-instead-of-vim-buffer/332929#332929).